# Como fazer ação OnClick em Option de Select

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Preciso fazer uma ação onclick em cada option de um select com um link diferente de acordo com o id de cada, porém não está funcionando.

```
$label .= "<select size=\"1\" name=\"modulo\" class='form-control'";

$label .= "<option value=\"0\" selected=\"selected\" onclick=\"javascript:document.location.href='admin_solicitacoes.php?DfStatus=$DfStatus&modulo=0&desenvolvimento=$desenvolvimento&tipo=$tipo&plataforma=$plataforma'\">Todos</option>";

$sql_buscar_modulo = "SELECT DfIdModulo, DfDescricao FROM $tbModulo ORDER BY DfDescricao ASC";
$resultado_buscar_modulo = mysql_query($sql_buscar_modulo)
or die ("$mysql_erro");

while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado_buscar_modulo)) {
    $DfIdModulo = $linha["DfIdModulo"];
    $DfDescricao = stripslashes($linha["DfDescricao"]);

    $label .= "<option value=\"$DfIdModulo\" onclick=\"javascript:document.location.href='admin_solicitacoes.php?DfStatus=$DfStatus&modulo=$DfIdModulo&desenvolvimento=$desenvolvimento&tipo=$tipo&plataforma=$plataforma'\">$DfDescricao</option>";
}

$label .= "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lidar com redirecionamentos em Seletor(select) você pode usar o evento "onChange" para isso, veja:

```js
 document.getElementById("selector").onchange = function(){
      location.href = this.value;
    }
```

```html
<select id="selector">
    <option value="https://wwww.facebook.com.br/">Facebook</option>
    <option value="https://wwww.google.com.br/">Google</option>
    <option value="https://wwww.youtube.com/">Youtube</option>
  </select>
```

Caso te ajudei, não esqueça de deixar o voto! ^.